# Create Future DataFrame Date Column - Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a new dataframe date column based upon where another dataframe column date left off?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': ['2001-01-01','2001-01-02','2001-01-03', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05'],
        'prod': [800, 900, 1200, 700, 600]})

last_date = max(df1.date)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [9,1,18,4,5]})
```

Desired dataframe:

```
print(df2)

   value        date
0      9  2001-01-06
1      1  2001-01-07
2     18  2001-01-08
3      4  2001-01-09
4      5  2001-01-10
```

I've tried `df2['date'] = pd.date_range('2001-01-06', periods=20, freq='days')`, however this extends the length of df2.

Comment: `periods=len(df2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) after converting the `df1['date']` column to datetime:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.date_range(df1['date'].max()+pd.Timedelta(1,unit='d'),periods=len(df2))
```

---

```
print(df2)

   value       date
0      9 2001-01-06
1      1 2001-01-07
2     18 2001-01-08
3      4 2001-01-09
4      5 2001-01-10
```